# How to include code inside a grid in a question?

Tags: exam, grids

I'd like to ask a question in the exam class that gives code, but is not complete and needs to be completed. Of course I can use the `\fillin` command, but I think it would be better if there was a grid in the background and I could align the code on that grid (or vice versa), because the indentation plays a big role in Python code.

How can I achieve this?

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{listings} % or any other package useful for python(3) code                                                                                                                                                                        
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
  \question[1] \textbf{Completion test} Complete the following code so that the function returns the given value or False if not possible:
  \begin{lstlisting}[language=Python, keepspaces=true, escapechar=!]
      def just_an_example(n):
          try:
              return !\fillin[int]!(n)
          !\fillin[except ValueError:]!
              return False
  \end{lstlisting}

  \question[1] \textbf{Better completion test} It would be much nicer if the code were inside a grid (without \textbackslash{}fillin-command). How to achieve that?
  \fillwithgrid{8em}
  \begin{lstlisting}[language=Python, keepspaces=true, escapechar=!]
      def just_an_example(n):
          try:
              return       (n)

              return False
  \end{lstlisting}
  This should be inside the grid not outside.
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```